# Need help centering text on an image that is within a grid

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox, centering

I am new to both stackoverflow and at using HTML & CSS, so apologize in advance for any rookie mistakes I may make.

My goal is to create a menu with a grid of options that are pictures once you hover over one of the pictures it will blur and a corresponding text will appear in the center of the picture.

I want to place objects like these: https://codepen.io/Polyglotton/pen/BapOLBO

within a responsive grid.

This is what I have so far;
https://codepen.io/Polyglotton/pen/jOyvMQb

The issue I am running into is that once in the grid the text is no longer centered.
I believe the possible solution would be to put the text within its own `<div>`, I have tried my hand at this but not matter what `position` I use I still end up with the text somewhere outside of the picture instead of inside.
The closest I have come to getting the text centered is by creating a new `class`. In the second link, on the first row second column, I tried this, I got the yellow text to "appear" centered but if I resize the browser the text moves all over the place so this is not an optimal solution.
So does anyone know what the best solution would be to getting the text centered once again?

As I said I am new to both HTML and CSS, so I would also like to know if using a responsive grid(flexbox) is efficient? or would it be easier to just set this with a table?

Thanks for any insights anyone can provide thank you.

Comment: a quick one, i added some flex box to it. I'm not sure exactly how you want it to look as the screen gets smaller, for eg you may want to control it using @media. But for now, heres my code pen: https://codepen.io/jennift/pen/MWJqmMX

Answer (score 0):

This is what u need

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
    width: 30%;
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
}

.item img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.item .textWithBlurredBg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display:none;
}

.item:hover .textWithBlurredBg{
  display:flex;
}

.item:hover img{
   filter:blur(2px) brightness(60%);
   box-shadow:0 0 16px #53bdcb;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<a href="" class="item">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/UXxIkAu.jpeg" />
  <div class="textWithBlurredBg">
    <h2 class="inner-txt">Go Hiking!
   </h2>
  </div>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your help, I attempted your solution, and it does center the text but I ran into other issues. for example the blur is gone, and also when having more than one of the object they are too spaced apart on the left and right but then overlap on the top and bottom

Comment: can u edit your post above with the new code? and let me see your code

Comment: Hello, sorry I was a bit busy these past few days but I put the code you gave me into code pen and somehow got the blur to appear. but I still run into the issue where some of the pictures collide. Here is the link: https://codepen.io/Polyglotton/pen/ExZdrdL